# Horror Movie Poster Remake

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to copy this poster

[image]

strictly for learning. I do not plan to use it in any way whatsoever.

Te graveyard image used is this one here at:

[image: http://stock-karr.deviantart.com/art/St-Annes-Cemetery-2-84715736]

My major problem is with how to obtain the misty, dark bluish sky in the background.
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

My attempt:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TduJ0.jpg]

Comment: Buffy isn't horror is it? :p

Comment: Yup! But, closer to horror than anything else.

Comment: One suggestion to improve your current design. The bats and yellow eyes detract from your graphic and draw attention away from the moon/buffy focus, I'd take them out to make a more focussed design.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Create a new layer over the graveyard
- Fill it with `#2d3e71`.
- Set style to "Multiply".
- It should look like this now: [image]
- Get a random sky image from the internet, I used: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/Appearance_of_sky_for_weather_forecast,_Dhaka,_Bangladesh.JPG
- Put it in a new layer on top of everything.
- Resize it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> so that it just barely covers the work space.
- Set style to "Multiply".
- Now you applied the blue color `#2d3e71` and the sky pattern on the graveyard.
- It was too dark for my taste, so I lightened it up a bit:

  - Select sky layer.
  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and set middle arrow to 2.66.
- Result:[image]

Basically you just play around with layers of the color and the pattern you want to mix with the original one. Try all settings and different opacities to learn how they work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a solid blue fill over the graveyard and play with the blend modes, for the light ray use the pen tool to draw a solid shape and then blur it out with gaussian blur, again play with the blend modes.

Comment: Trying.Will experimenting also involve Levels or Curves? Because I can't get it to look with simple blending modes.
Thank you for your timely reply! Appreciate the effort.

Comment: Experimenting involves everything! The best way to learn Photoshop is by messing with it. At least it worked for me!